# access server with ip address and not server name

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ip, redirect, django

I am trying to access my server to the following address:

```
https://www.media-rewards.com/
```

But it doesn't work :(.

However, if I use its ip address, it works:

```
https://52.0.245.209/
```

I don't know if the two problems are linked, but: I can access the defaut apache page (/var/www/html/index.html)

```
http://52.0.245.209/
```

I would like to redirect it to the https address, what I tried in the apache configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.media-rewards.com
   Redirect permanent /var/www/html https://www.media-rewards.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.media-rewards.com
    Redirect permanent /var/www/html https://www.media-rewards.com/
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Why do you say that `https://52.0.245.209/` works? Correct behavior would be for the browser to produce an error on that URL, since there aren't supposed to exist any valid certificate for a URL using an IP address rather than a domain name.

Comment: Well, it works but the https is crossed in the browser. I guess it indicates the certificate is not recognized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because the A record in DNS for `www.media-rewards.com` doesn't point to `52.0.245.209`, but rather `54.76.29.199`.

```
# dig www.media-rewards.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 <<>> www.media-rewards.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18713
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.media-rewards.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.media-rewards.com.  10800   IN      A       54.76.29.199

;; Query time: 335 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 25 07:23:20 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: You're right! 54.76.29.199 was the old server. How do I fix it?

Comment: That depends entirely on your environment, and without knowing more about it it's hard to say. If you're paying for hosting, you likely have some sort of control panel that will let you do it. If it's a VPS or Colo, then things get even more specific to your particulars.

Comment: I am using gandi for my domain name. I just edited the A record with the right ip address (in the control panel of gandi). However, when I run your command, I still see the old ip address. I think it takes a few hours for the changes to be effective...

Comment: Correct, it does indeed a take a few hours; at least 3 based on the TTL from your zone (10800).